# Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting error while executing the angular project. Please see the screenshot.
Please help me.
[image]

Comment: Where's the screenshot?

Comment: Already attached.

Comment: You're using a recent version of angular CLI, expecting an angular.json file, with a project that ws created wil an old version of angular CLI, expecting a .angular-cli.json file. You need to use the original cli version, or to upgrade your project.

Comment: How can I upgrade my project. please suggest.

Comment: after running the command "ng update @angular/cli --save", I'm getting the below message.
Package not installed: "@angular/cli". Skipping. We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

With new CLI it should be named as **`angular.json`** instead of **`angular-cli.json`**

you may need to save your changes try run this:

```
 ng update @angular/cli --save
```

Comment: after running the above command, I'm getting the below message.

Comment: Package not installed: "@angular/cli". Skipping.
We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

I Supposed your project is use an old version of angular cli (this use the `angular-cli.json` file) and on your computer is a newer version that require the `angular.json` instead.

In order to archieve this you should run **ng update @angular/cli --save**. Somethimes it require to run this twice. Then you should have an updated project.

[The official documentation for updates](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update) allow the flag `migrate-only`. This can be usefull if you only want to archieve a migration and not a complete update. then run: 
`ng update @angular/cli --from=x.x.x --migrate-only` where `x.x.x` represents your actual version of cli.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error because angular-cli version you are using is new which is for angular 6 while your code is in angular 5 or low. You would need to update some your dependencies to get it running. After you follow steps mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@pratik_m23/upgrading-angular-4-5-to-angular-6-9babee60cea6) your `.anglar-cli.json` file would be converted to `angular.json` file and you would be able to run the project.

Answer (score -1):

Your Angular CLI is on a later version than the project uses. The later version uses `angular.json` while the older version uses `.angular-cli.json`.

You can rename `.angular-cli.json`. to `angular.json` to remove the error message.

Comment: Just renaming the file will probably not work. The structure of the file and the behavior of the CLI has changed, too. The project needs to be upgraded.

Comment: We'll you could install a local Angular CLI with the older version the project is using.